# select multiple rows and edit those multiple rows in a table using linq asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have table like below

[image]

Once I pass Product_ID as "01" I want to expand all relevant rows into editor view and once I submit those save those values into this table.

For GET method I need to select relevant rows and put those vaue intor edit boxes

So I create my get method like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Product_Edit(string Product_ID)
    {
        Product_ID = "01";

        var product_fields = (from productstatistics in db.AB_Product_vs_Field
                              where productstatistics.Product_ID == Product_ID
                              select new AB_Product_vs_Field
                             {
                                Product_ID = productstatistics.Product_ID,
                                Field_ID = productstatistics.Field_ID,
                                Field_Value_EN = productstatistics.Field_Value_EN,
                                Field_Value_AR = productstatistics.Field_Value_AR
                             }).ToList();

        if (product_fields == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }


        return View(product_fields);

    }
```

but here I'm getting following exception message

> The entity or complex type 'project_name.table_name' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

**EDIT** : this is the [view page](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/5Eap5/product-edit)

Comment: Could you please provide your view page code or code from where this error was raised.

Comment: @JayeshGoyani I updated the question , error occur in beginning of the LINQ query

Comment: The view is strongly types view and its model is 'AB_Product_vs_Field' and you are passing list 'List<AB_Product_vs_Field>' in-place of object 'AB_Product_vs_Field' in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select `product_fields` like following.

```
var product_fields = db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Where(p=>p.Product_ID==Product_ID);
```

Since it return a list you view model should be

```
@model List<project_name.Models.AB_Product_vs_Field>
```

And in you view use a `foreach` loop to show all data like following.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Product_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Product_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Product_ID, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
    @*others information goes here*@
}
```

[This](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XUJYAX) dotnet fiddle may be helpful for you.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/XUJYAX

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Product_Edit(string Product_ID)
{
    Product_ID = "01";

    var product_fields = (from productstatistics in db.AB_Product_vs_Field
                          where productstatistics.Product_ID == Product_ID
                          select productstatistics).ToList();

    if (product_fields == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }


    return View(product_fields);

}
```

You are selecting all the fields so you don't have to create a anonymous object.

Comment: then getting this error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[project_name.Models.table_name]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'project_name.Models.table_name'`